# How can I use lodash merge to combine properties that have different casing

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

Hello so my issue with merge currently is my db has two variables that I unfortunately cannot change the names of the variables to match each other manually. Thus I'm wondering if I can somehow modify jquery's merge to combine two objects and add the variables together ignoring case.

Such as:

```
var object = {
'a': [ { 'b':2 }, {'d':4}]
};

var other = {
'A': [{'c': 3}, {'e':5}]
};

_.merge(object, other);
// -> {'a': [{'b': 2, 'c':3}, {'d':4, 'e':5}] }
```

The current merge method in our lodash library:

```
/**
     * Recursively merges own enumerable properties of the source object(s), that
     * don't resolve to `undefined` into the destination object. Subsequent sources
     * will overwrite property assignments of previous sources. If a callback is
     * provided it will be executed to produce the merged values of the destination
     * and source properties. If the callback returns `undefined` merging will
     * be handled by the method instead. The callback is bound to `thisArg` and
     * invoked with two arguments; (objectValue, sourceValue).
     *
     * @static
     * @memberOf _
     * @category Objects
     * @param {Object} object The destination object.
     * @param {...Object} [source] The source objects.
     * @param {Function} [callback] The function to customize merging properties.
     * @param {*} [thisArg] The `this` binding of `callback`.
     * @returns {Object} Returns the destination object.
     * @example
     *
     * var names = {
     *   'characters': [
     *     { 'name': 'barney' },
     *     { 'name': 'fred' }
     *   ]
     * };
     *
     * var ages = {
     *   'characters': [
     *     { 'age': 36 },
     *     { 'age': 40 }
     *   ]
     * };
     *
     * _.merge(names, ages);
     * // => { 'characters': [{ 'name': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'name': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }
     *
     * var food = {
     *   'fruits': ['apple'],
     *   'vegetables': ['beet']
     * };
     *
     * var otherFood = {
     *   'fruits': ['banana'],
     *   'vegetables': ['carrot']
     * };
     *
     * _.merge(food, otherFood, function(a, b) {
     *   return _.isArray(a) ? a.concat(b) : undefined;
     * });
     * // => { 'fruits': ['apple', 'banana'], 'vegetables': ['beet', 'carrot] }
     */
      var args = arguments,
        length = 2;

      if (!isObject(object)) {
        return object;
      }
      // allows working with `_.reduce` and `_.reduceRight` without using
      // their `index` and `collection` arguments
      if (typeof args[2] != 'number') {
        length = args.length;
      }
      if (length > 3 && typeof args[length - 2] == 'function') {
        var callback = baseCreateCallback(args[--length - 1], args[length--], 2);
      } else if (length > 2 && typeof args[length - 1] == 'function') {
        callback = args[--length];
      }
      var sources = slice(arguments, 1, length),
        index = -1,
        stackA = getArray(),
        stackB = getArray();

      while (++index < length) {
        baseMerge(object, sources[index], callback, stackA, stackB);
      }
      releaseArray(stackA);
      releaseArray(stackB);
      return object;

  };
```

Thank you all for your time looking into this with me!

Comment: will you always be dealing with two results - for example 'A' and 'a' or 'B' and 'b'?

Comment: Do you want the key's to always be lowercase, does it matter, or do you need to keep the case from the original object?

Comment: @tsturzl I need to keep the case from the original object and no it could be more than one result.

Comment: @abigwonderful The example I used mimics the example from the lodash api with the minor change of making 'a' uppercase. So there could be a case where I need to do this with multiple properties provided they are the same name (ignoring case).

Comment: and will the multiple properties be known or will this be a dynamic matching process?

Comment: @abigwonderful dynamic matching process.

Comment: thinking maybe a sample of your results might be helpful

Comment: @abigwonderful Give me a moment I'll add the method we currently have into the query.

Comment: cool. just added an answer that will probably need work, but wondering if it's moving in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started taking this way too deep, but wondering if a simple function that converts properties to lowercase might help:

```
var obj1 = {
'a': [ { 'b':2 }, {'d':4}]
};

var obj2 = {
'A': [{'c': 3}, {'e':5}]
};

function propsToLower(obj){
    var newObj ={};
    for(var item in obj){
        newObj[item.toLowerCase()] = obj[item];
    }
    return newObj;
}

var newObj1 = propsToLower(obj1);
var newObj2 = propsToLower(obj2);

_.merge(newObj1, newObj2);
```

Comment: That looks awesome! I'll just have to find out if I can change the casing on the properties to be all lowercase or keep one of the original casing on one of the objects. For the meanwhile though thank you very much for a push in the right direction =D

Comment: yeah if you know that one will always be lowercase, then no need to run the function on both. Just wanted to be certain.

Comment: @BenJohnson This is what I was going to suggest but you said "I need to keep the case from the original object". If you want to preserve the original case from the first object you're going to have to do a lot more than this and likely write your own `merge` method.